# Send Email to Outlook Exchange Contact Email Address

Tags: c#, email, outlook, addressbook

I read from Outlook Contacts my Contacts and then I add the Contact to `MailMessage mail.To.Add("John Doe <John Doe>")` but I receive this error:

> *The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail address.*

How can I resolve this? when I read from Outlook Contacts the result for email address is a long string like this (*only for Exchange account types*) and I prse to get the last cn= value:
`/o=First Organization/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)/cn=Recipients/cn=John Doe`

How can I read the correct e-mail address from an Exchange Account (`jDoe@example.com`) or other method to send e-mail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an [`ExchangeUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff866281.aspx), you can access the property [`PrimarySmtpAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862991.aspx) for the Exchange email. Then the following should work for you...

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.To.Add(exchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress);
```

Comment: thanks this worked i got the exchangeuser from addressEntry.GetExchangeUser();